# flutter gridView child height is fixed, add other widget cannot show?

Tags: flutter

here:
[image]

[image]

below the picture there is an inline text, but it is not visible. Maybe be the picture's height takes up the whole height? Any idea?

Comment: Can you insert the code as text instead of showing an image. This makes sure that the question can still be informative if the image host goes down, and it allows other people to copy your code, which will assist them in answering the question.

Comment: Also can you try to include a bit more information in words of what exactly you are trying to do? It is quite difficult to understand at the moment. Please see how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: too long code and cannot paste, sorry, i want to and a desc text under the grid item, that's it.

Comment: the grid should contain a column not a wrap, and the column will contain your stack and your desc

Comment: em, both of column and wrap look same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **GridView.builder**. Instead you can use **[GridView.count](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.count.html)**.

In **GridView.count**, there is a parameter `childAspectRatio` which you can use to increase the height of the grid.

Comment: not work, only change the picture width or height, the picture still cover the text

Comment: thanks, i modify childAsepectRatio property i looks well now